# Install fileinfo php extension

Tags: php, apache, putty, whm

As the fileinfo is moved from PECL to PHP. What is the best way to install it through WHM or putty.?

I tried following command:

```
pecl install fileinfo
```

and received following error:

> WARNING: "pear/Fileinfo" is deprecated in favor of "channel://php-src/ext/fileinfo/in php sources
>
> "WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update    pear.php.net" to update
>
> downloading Fileinfo-1.0.4.tgz ...
>
> Starting to download Fileinfo-1.0.4.tgz (5,835 bytes)
>
> .....done: 5,835 bytes
>
> 3 source files, building
>
> running: phpize
>
> Cannot find config.m4.
>
> Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
>
> ERROR: `phpize' failed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. Before this time, fileinfo was a PECL extension but is no longer maintained there. However, versions prior to 5.3+ may use the » [discontinued PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/fileinfo).

**Reference:**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

---

```
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

This error is displayed because you don't have `php-devel` package installed

Comment: how can i install php-devel through whm or putty.

Answer (score 7):

Are you install php-devel?
phpize execute need's php-devel package. if you are on centos run the following code

```
yum install php-devel
```

Comment: I tried the command mentioned by you but it results:

Setting up Install Process
No package php-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: you need to install epel yum's package to install following this link [link](http://www.andresmontalban.com/update-centos-5-php-5-1-to-php-5-3/)

Comment: On CentOS try: `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php54 install php-devel`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this, and needed to install php-fileinfo for WHM on a VPS Dedicated server. This https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to-install-a-php-extension-using-easyapache-4/
was very helpful. I figured id post this for the next guy.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is working

```
#yum install rh-php70-php-devel
```

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh/rh-php70-php-devel-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html