# File Exception error laravel and fileinfo extension dependency

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl, fileinfo, php-5.5

Could Not Install / Enable fileinfo extension

I have referred to this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194105/1679510

which says fileinfo is by default enabled i php5.3+

I have php5.5.9 on my ubuntu, but php.ini file did not have any filenfo extension information.

I have also checked `/etc/php5/mods-available` and no ini file for fileinfo

Running `pecl install fileinfo` give depricatd error, which is expected.

How to install the fileinfo extension.

Edit1:

After running `php -m` fileinfo can be seen in the list, however the file exception error in laravel log lead me to debugg into this is -> http://pastebin.com/FaENLrLH

Is it really a fileinfo error? or something else?

Comment: yes its there fileinfo :-) .. so what next can i do to enable it ? (i am having file upload errors , and the developer reported it is dependent on fileinfo extension

Comment: Show your errors messages (do not trust developers : ) )...

Comment: its here http://pastebin.com/FaENLrLH  
Its a php script using lavarel framework. thanks for extended support :-)

Comment: This error does not rely on fileinfo extension. It's consequence of `is_uploaded_file` or `http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php` result. Ask developer to visit SO with his own question.

Comment: ok thanks. How can i close this thread?

Comment: You could do nothing % )